# Is it more readable to declare the return type of a function on the left side of it's name?

Tags: syntax, language-design, functions

A lot of C-like programming languages (Java, C#, ...) use the following syntax for defining functions:

```
returnType functionName(parameters...) {
}
```

Is there a particular reason to do it that way ? (to put the return type first, on the left side). It is, I think, less natural than defining the function name first, then the inputs, then the output.

One reason I can see is that it match the way it will be called later on:

```
returnValue = functionName(...);
```

Some other languages (like Pascal, Rust, ...) put the return type on the right side:

```
function functionName(parameters...): returnType;
begin

end
```

Comment: Does this answer your question? [What are the advantages/disadvantages of prefix type syntax?](https://langdev.stackexchange.com/questions/205/what-are-the-advantages-disadvantages-of-prefix-type-syntax) (also, welcome to PLDI!)

Comment: Is there a specific conception of "readability" you have in mind? Are you looking for empirical results? Is this a historical question about how this came about in existing systems? Please [edit] to narrow down the question to one particular version that can be given objective answers.

Comment: @RydwolfPrograms yes it does. I did a quick search before asking and did not find that answer.